# why mongodb on 32-bit machine has limitation of datasize to 2GB , not 4GB?

Tags: mongodb

as [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#faq-32-bit-limitations) mention, mongodb has  limitation of datasize to 2GB in 32-bit machine with one single mongod instance. But I wonder 32-bit machine has 4GB addressable space in theory, and mongod can use this 4GB instead of 2GB for virtual memory usage. So why the answer is 2GB, not 4GB?

Comment: does this post on their blog help ? http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I saw this post before, but it does not explain why? I want to know how to calculate out the result:2GB.

Comment: i guess (i'm not the one designing mongoDB), 2GB for data, rest of the size is for mapping, and other supporting files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

4Gb of addressable space is not the same as the memory space available for memory-mapped files opened by user applications. Some of the addressable space is reserved for the O/S kernel and memory-mapped devices such as video cards.

For example, 32-bit Windows limits user mode (and thus memory-mapped files) to ~2Gb RAM and total system RAM to ~3.5Gb.

For more reading, see:

- [Coding Horror: Dude, Where's My 4 Gigabytes of RAM?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/dude-wheres-my-4-gigabytes-of-ram.html)
- [MSDN: Managing Memory-Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx)
- [MSDN: Memory-Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx)

The majority of modern desktop and server environments starting moving to 64-bit almost a decade ago (see [64-bit operating system timeline on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#64-bit_operating_system_timeline)) so this isn't a limit that practically affects deployment.

You would only want to use 32-bit MongoDB in a development environment with limited data.

Answer (score 2):

> 32-bit MongoDB processes are limited to about 2 gb of data.  This has come as a surprise to a lot of people who are used to not having to worry about that.  The reason for this is that the MongoDB storage engine uses memory-mapped files for performance.
>
> By not supporting more than 2gb on 32-bit, we’ve been able to keep our code much simpler and cleaner.  This greatly reduces the number of bugs, and reduces the time that we need to release a 1.0 product.

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations

Comment: ha, almost the same second we post

Comment: I saw this post before, but it does not explain why? I want to know how to calculate out the result:2GB.

Comment: Or you mean this limitation has no rules to calculate , and just mongodb settings?

Comment: Yes. Read the blog post carefully. It's not strictly due to the 32-bit ness, but that limiting to "about 2 gb" makes the code simpler – so clearly it's very implementation-dependent.

Comment: The limit on size of memory-mapped files is imposed by the operating system, so "about 2Gb" is a guideline rather than a hard limit in the code. The conscious decision was to focus on 64-bit servers rather than trying to implement complicated workarounds to map more memory on 32-bit computers (which may only amount to an extra Gb or so depending on the O/S).